# How to get NONE existing records from 2 entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, fetch

I have 2 entities in CRM, many-1 relationship.

Entity A, Entity B -- 1-many

How can I write FetchXML to get all records that are not in entity B

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what query you want. Can you rephrase?

If you can create the query in Advanced Find, you can extract the FetchXML out of it.  See [Using the Advanced Find for FetchXML builder](http://ronaldlemmen.blogspot.com/2006/11/using-advanced-find-for-fetchxml.html).

Another great way to write FetchXML is by using [Stunnware Tools for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 - Overview](http://www.stunnware.com/?area=products&group=swtools4).  The free Community edition has an awesome FetchXML builder that can construct queries even slightly more complicated than Advanced Find.  When you extract the tools, you might have to enable the FetchXML builder in the options.  The FetchXML builder interface took me a while to get used to because you access most functionality via right-clicking.